# Spread into array of literal types

Tags: typescript

I want to do this in Typescript:

```
type animals = 'cat' | 'dog'

let selectedAnimals: animals[] = ['cat']

selectedAnimals = [ // <- Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'animals[]'
    ...selectedAnimals,
    ...(condition ? ['cat'] : [])
]
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgdgSwLYwDYGcoF4oHIDGMwuUAPngCYD2A5rgFD2oTBToTP7AQUCCiKDAC5YAtOgDaAXWxQJBIrimN67Ttz5iMsifSj6oAOmNqIXHv2TiANHoPHDACnmFiUgJT0pQA).

The following works, but is there a nicer way than using `as animals`?

```
type animals = 'cat' | 'dog'

let selectedAnimals: animals[] = ['cat']

selectedAnimals = [
    ...selectedAnimals,
    ...(['cat' as animals]),
    ...(['wednesday' as animals]) // <- this also compiles
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `as const` to `['cat']` to give it type `readonly ["cat"]` instead of `string[]`, and the code will compile without losing type safety. This will also guard against including non-animal arrays:

```
type animals = 'cat' | 'dog'

let selectedAnimals: animals[] = ['cat']

selectedAnimals = [
    ...selectedAnimals,
    ...(['cat'] as const),
    // ...(['wednesday'] as const) // <- will fail
]
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgdgSwLYwDYGcoF4oHIDGMwuUAPngCYD2A5rgFD2oTBToTP7AQUCCiKDAC5YAtOgDaAXWxQJBIrimN2nbnzEZZE+lD1QAdEdUQuPfsnEAaXfqMGAFPMLEZMTPipx0wAJQ39KAB6IMMjJ1wAdx44CHQKGBAlWA8vH19g0IAeAFooSIRUVCgAMxhC+mUgA)

Alternatively, you could add `as const` to the individual elements, e.g. `` [`cat` as const] `` which will type the array as `"cat"[]`. ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgdgSwLYwDYGcoF4oHIDGMwuUAPngCYD2A5rgFD2oTBToTP7AQUCCiKDAC5YAtOgDaAXWxQJBIrimN2nbnzEZZE%20lD1QAdEdUQuPfsnEAaXfqMGAFPMLFYmfFTjpgUgJQ39KAB6IMMjJ1wAdx44CHQKGBASGHdPbz9g0IAeAFooSIRUVCgAMxhC%20mUgA))